# How to check if mediaplayer is playing or stopped?

Tags: java, media-player, jmf

How can I check whether the mediaplayer is playing or stopped, using Java Media Framework?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can call [`getState`](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E17802_01/j2se/javase/technologies/desktop/media/jmf/2.1.1/apidocs/javax/media/bean/playerbean/MediaPlayer.html#getState%28%29) and check against [`Controller.Started`](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E17802_01/j2se/javase/technologies/desktop/media/jmf/2.1.1/apidocs/javax/media/Controller.html#Started):

```
if (mediaPlayer.getState() == Controller.Started)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
// Register ControllerListener :

public class myPlayer implements ControllerListener  {
// ....
    Player player = Manager.createRealizedPlayer(url);
    player.addControllerListener(this);
// ....


// And check for EndOfMedia event in the controllerUpdate method:

    public void controllerUpdate(ControllerEvent event) {
    if (event instanceof EndOfMediaEvent) {
        // Take appropriate action
        }
    }
} // End of class
```

By checking the state and by listening to EndOfMedia event, one could detect if media is being played or stopped.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like a bit changed since the accepted answer.
The following works for me:

```
if(this.player.getStatus() == MediaPlayer.Status.STOPPED){
     // Do something
}
```