# How to check if MediaPlayer is stopped?

Tags: android, media-player, media, android-mediaplayer

The answer here
    [How to check if mediaplayer is playing or stopped?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10491032/how-to-check-if-mediaplayer-is-playing-or-stopped)
does not work to me.
It seems that MediaPlayer does not have the getState method.
Is this method depreciated?

Thanks,

Comment: Android's `MediaPlayer` class is different from the `MediaPlayer` used in the mentioned StackOverflow question, hence the missing method.

Comment: Did you try Patel's answer ?

Answer (score 2):

Try with the below code:

```
MediaPlayer mp = new MediaPlayer();
...
...
if(mp.isPlaying())
    //YOU LOGIC IF PLAYER IS PLAYING
else
    //YOU LOGIC IF PLAYER IS NOT PLAYING
```

Ref Link: [http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaPlayer.html#isPlaying()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaPlayer.html#isPlaying%28%29)

Hope it will help you..

Comment: In the diagram http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaPlayer.html#StateDiagram, I think we still cannot distinguish Prepared and Stopped when isPlaying() is false.

Comment: In my case, I wanted to design an audio controller with start, pause, stop, next buttons. I think my initial state should be Prepared which is after a user chose a song, and my app prepared the song. Then the user can pause or stop it. The problem is that after pause, I can call MediaPlayer.start() directly, but after stop, I have to re-prepare the song before calling start. This is why I asked. Does my logical make sense? Maybe I should use other logic or maintain the state manually in my code? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

If you have troubles with re-starting the [MediaPlayer](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaPlayer.html) after stopping it, then try this:

```
if (mMediaPlayer != null) {
    mMediaPlayer.stop();
    try {
        mMediaPlayer.prepare();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        Log.e(LOG_TAG, "IOException during prepare after stop! mMediaPlayer value: " + mMediaPlayer);
    }
}
```

You basically prepare it for the next start. It worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

Set a flag when you call player.stop().

```
palyer.stop();
isStop = true;
if(isStop){
    // Do someing 
    isStop = false;
}
```

Comment: This seems to be the cleanest and best way to handle the problem. I came across this problem while developing a video app, and this is how I solved it. In the "Do something" part, just add `player.prepare()`.